# geocoder.geocode function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Hi I want to geocode a location which users entered.

but it seems the geocoder.geocode function does not work

here is that part of the JavaScript

```
$('#inputButtonGeocode').click(function () {
var sAddress = document.getElementById('inputTextAddress').value;
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': sAddress
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
});
```

it should be a simple problem, but i cannot find the issue

he is the JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/u2gP3/7/.

Could anyone help me please, Thank you

Comment: I get a javascript error in your fiddle: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geocode' of undefined`.  You haven't included the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  Your "map" is an embedded map, that doesn't support geocoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are a few things. It doesn't appear as thought your initialize function is ever being run and therefore your geocoder object is never going to be made. As well this API is not compatible with the google maps embed (iframe) API. 
  You can see in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) example that they are creating both a geocoder and then a map using the following to create the map:

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);`

They are assigning the map to a variable called map. And then they are using that variable to pass into the creation of a marker so that that marker is placed on the right map..

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
```

Also don't forget to load the actual google maps api. The jquery plugin gives you the ability to handle events in the map but it doesn't actually load the api. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) is an example of loading the API asynchronously. You can also load it like any other script, simple and easy,  seen [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API).

Comment: Hi I have tried the sample code you suggested, and add the jquery.ui.map.full.min.js to the external file, but I cannot see the maps, did i miss something? here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/u2gP3/13/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I can't really do anything with your code because it is incomplete. If you want I can help you debug it but you need to create a js fiddle that has the entire html and java-script. I am also going to update my answer with what I think your problem is.

Comment: hi actually I have solved the problem, just added more specific ids,And also I missed the API, i thought my framework has already contained but it does not.  thanks for helping :-)

Comment: No worries glad you got it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to refer the correct `window` Object. Your JavaScript is on a separate page from your iframe. You could use `var theWindow = frames[number].contentWindow || frames[number].contentDocument;`. Of course then you need CORS access. I would just not use an iframe. Also, I don't see your `initialize()` function ever being called. Is `new google.maps.Map();` somewhere else? You can use the Google Maps API to load the map directly into the Element of your choice, without using an iframe. The bottom line you have to have a `Map` Object created with `new google.maps.Map()`. It will look something like:

```
var g = google.maps;
var map = new g.Map($('#map'), {zoom:8, center:new g.LatLng(43.472285,-80.544858)});
```

Of course, you can add and change attributes to the `MapOpitons` Object. Only after you've made a map do you have access to create a `new g.Marker()`. Note: I shorten `google.maps` to `g` to avoid repetitive typing.